# Get access to BitBake build configuration variables

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a BitBake/Yocto question. I am building a project which uses Poky and some custom layers added on top of it. While the project is built it outputs "Build Configuration" that includes details like `BB_VERSION`, `BUILD_SYSTEM`, `DISTRO_NAME`, etc. It also has git branch name and version for all included layers like `meta-<layer_name> : "<branch_name>:<revision_hash>"`. I am trying to access branch name and revision for custom layers added from the recipe but could not find a way to get access to it. Also these branch detail variables are lowercase vs other example variables that I listed above are uppercase. I am not sure if that makes any difference as I can access those uppercase variables during build but can't access the ones with lower case.

Would anyone have any clue how can I get git branch name and version via these variables without having to use `git` commands. Currently I am executing git commands to get those details. I have looked in BitBake documentation and the closest I could find was `METADATA_BRANCH` variable which gives me `meta-yocto-bsp` layer branch details.

Comment: From where you want to access the variables? From a recipe ?

Comment: Yes, from one of the recipes, sorry updated my question now.

Answer (score 0):

The part where layers and their versions are printed are done by a function, not from plain variables.  Check `BUILDCFG_FUNCS` for a list of functions that print build configuration data and specifically the `get_layers_branch_rev` function for the layer data